# Transform object type, keep key-value relationship

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an object type, e.g.:

```js
interface A {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz: boolean;
  // …
}
```

How can I transform it using a generic type into something very different while keeping the key-value relationship?

For instance, I might need `{ key, value }` objects:

```js
type KeyValueObject =
  | { key: 'foo'; value: string; }
  | { key: 'bar'; value: number; }
  | { key: 'baz'; value: boolean; }
// | …
```

or a function that accepts the key-value pairs as arguments:

```js
type KeyValueHandler =
  | (key: 'foo', value: string) => Promise<string>
  | (key: 'bar', value: number) => Promise<number>
  | (key: 'baz', value: boolean) => Promise<boolean>
// | …
```

I thought [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) must hold the answer, but I couldn't figure out how to use them for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mapped types are indeed the answer - [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) answer finally got me going.*

A mapped type combined with a property lookup does the trick.

```js
type KeyValueObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { key: K; value: T[K] };
}[keyof T];

// for demonstration only - the result of this is quite useless
type KeyValueAsyncTransformer<T, R> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (key: K, value: T[K]) => Promise<T[K]>;
}[keyof T];
```